# What's Kratom, the coffee-like herb?

Tags: coffee-culture

So what is this kratom?

Saw it on Facebook, something about trump banning it.

I looked it up and it is a coffee like herb, possibly with psychedelic effects.

Anyhow... Can someone give me some insight on it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Mitragyna spinosa is typically seen as recreational drug or herb for traditional medicine, not even as coffee substitute.